# C# Control Pane remove or create keyboard shortcut for default menu and "size" option

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, vsto, accessibility

I am currently in the final stages of releasing an add-in to Microsoft Word 2010 (this likely works for other versions of word as well) using C#, winforms, and Visual Studio Tools for Office. The goal was to create a quick tool to do some office automation and most of the code is written so I would like to avoid significant rewrites. I am very close to release but I work for a large organization that has rigorous accessibility checks. Their current issue is that the pane has a menu that the user can use to resize the pane.

The menu that is causing me all these problems:

[image]

Resizing the pane is not important, but the accessibility reviews insist that any visual element must be fully accessible by keyboard to a motor impaired user. First, I would like to know what this menu is called - I have been searching everywhere but can't find reference to it.

Second, I have three options, each of which would solve the problem, but none of which I know how to

1. I could make keyboard shortcuts that call that specific menu.
2. I could make keyboard shortcuts that call the same function as the "Size" feature of that menu (when you press "Size" the mouse snaps to the side of the Control Pane and allows the user to maker it larger or smaller) without actually calling it directly from the menu.
3. I could remove or disable the menu (apparently, if I can simply make that menu visible but inaccessible to all users that would satisfy the accessibility reviewer as it would prove that it is not a needed function).

Again, I do not know how to do any of the three options I listed there. Any help in doing so using C# in Visual Studio Tools for Office would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of simply down-voting me, would you mind explaining how I can improve my question? I don't think it's helpful to just ensure no one will answer a new users questions when I think it is clear that I at least tried to be specific and explain my situation. Also I'm sorry that I don't have code to show, but on this issue I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: Wouldnt you just put the keyboard shortcut in the menu item text? ie &Close

Comment: @Saruman he didn't create the menu, Word did. @MichaelB Have you tried accessing the controls from the `TaskPane` object or `ActionsPane` object (for document-level solutions)? I'm not familiar with winforms but it has a few fields that sound promising, e.g. `Site`.

Comment: I have no experience in this area, but I do know that Microsoft has made Accessibility APIs for various things in Office, such as the Ribbon. Googling that for the actions pane I get two hits that might be useful for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/accessibility-in-office-projects and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.actionspane.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396